# AWS Workspace Windows Admin Access

Tags: workspace

Have created an AWS workspace that is Windows 10.
Need to have administrator rights within Windows 10 to be able to view/edit the C: drive, etc.
Have been reading the AWS documentation, but not finding a way to do this... things about admin rights are about administration rights external to the workspace, not to Windows 10 admin rights within it.

What do I need to do to give my existing Windows 10 user admin rights, or to create another user that has admin rights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the user provided by AWS *is* an admin user,  but the C: drive is hidden.
It can be accessed by manually typing "c:" in the Windows Explorer address bar.
Alternatively, per a post in AWS forum, C drive is hidden through a registry edit.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ Explorer
Dword Value - NoDrives; by default it is set to Hexidecimal value